# Passwords not remembered

Tags: iis-7, cookies

We'r running an IIS7 with our .NET4 aspx C# solution ontop as a site. I'm getting reports that some users experience their passwords needs to be retyped at times.

I told my boss that is a client side cookie issue, from what knowledge I have of the field. Boss told me it most often happens after update/release of our site. With my knowledge of the field (IIS, webserver), I'm not able to mess with cookies on the client side (intentionally or otherwise).

The only thing I can come up with is the release script, shuts down the site service while files are being replaced. After completion the site is started again. I have no knowledge if that messes with the cookies or passwords.

Does restarting the IIS service cause an issue with client side stored cookies ?

Any other suggestions as to where I need to research next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you restart IIS, it wipes the internal session cache that keeps track of sessions, which is what causes that behavior. The only thing that might work around this is to use your own cookie handling instead of the built-in .NET sessions.

Comment: Thank you. I confirmed it afterwards from MSDN, now I had something to go. Bummer for me.